# Programmatically "flashing" UITableViewCell sets background color to white

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uigesturerecognizer

I have `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` set in my `UICollectionView` which calls

```
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:self.collectionView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:point];
        if (indexPath) {
            self.manager.currentLongPressIndex = indexPath.row;
            [self showPopover];
        }
    }
}
```

The `UIPopover` shown from the method has a `UITableView`. My goal is to "flash" (select and then deselect `UITableViewCell`) and scroll to show it. This is how I do it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // get the current index path
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.manager.currentLongPressIndex inSection:0];
    // set flag
    self.cellIsFlashing = YES;
    // select cell
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.cellIsFlashing == NO) {
        [self.viewController.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    } else {
        self.cellIsFlashing = NO;
    }
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

This kinda works, but the selected cell's background color changes to white and the flash effect doesn't look good, it looks like it isn't animated at all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try delaying the deselection process:

```
-(void)deselectRow:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ... // your code here

    // call the deselect method with 0.3 second delay
    [self performSelector:@selector(deselectRow:) withObject:indexPath afterDelay:0.3f];
}
```

Not sure if this is going to work but worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by changing the cell selection code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear:animated:`